# Windows 7: How to disable folder contents "streaming"?

Tags: windows-7

When I open a folder with lots of files/folders, it will start to list the contents in small chunks, this is really annoying when I want to go to the end of the folder. I've noticed it also makes it slower to access the folders on Windows 7 compared to Windows XP.

So is there any way to remove this feature and go back to XP style ?

Answer (score 2):

File operations take time because compared to in memory operations, disk access is slow.  Windows coders have two choices - make you wait while reading everything before showing you anything or show it to you as it is read.  I guess it is a design choice.

I don't think you can "turn it off".  Best I can tell your only option is a really fast disk - think SSD. (or going back to XP, but that seems like a bad idea in so many ways).

Comment: well yeah, some cases the XP style is worser (if i have over 20k files), but i dont see point refreshing the contents view every 100ms... would be cool if i could adjust those timer values somehow? i had SSD but eventually it hung my computer a lot, so i threw it away.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the View slider to 'List' or 'Details'.  That should shut down the thumbnail loading.

Comment: i already use list setting